# Scraping all mobiles of Flipkart.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the mobiles from www.flipkart.com. Now, what I have thought of doing is that I can scrape all mobiles from here.

```
http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p[]=sort%3Dprice_asc&sid=tyy%2C4io&layout=grid
```

Now, the problem is that, in this website I have to press '**show more results**' to see more results. But, how can I do this using code? I am using BeautifulSoup package in python.

My code till now:

```
import bs4
import re
import urllib2
import sys

link = 'http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p[]=sort%3Dprice_asc&sid=tyy%2C4io&layout=grid'
response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
thePage = response.read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(thePage)
allMobiles = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'products'})
```

I only get the first page in the output? How can I access the other pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can play around with the get parameters. The regular URL is:

http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p[]=sort%3Dprice_asc&sid=tyy%2C4io&layout=grid

Once you hit the 'more results' button (or scroll down) the next page is loaded using AJAX with the following url:

http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dprice_asc&sid=tyy%2C4io&layout=grid&start=41&ajax=true

The url consists of the following parts:

- **path**: http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr
- **querystring**:

  - **p[]**: sort=price_asc
  - **sid**: tyy,4io
  - **layout**: grid
  - ***start**: 41*
  - **ajax**: true

If you want all phones, just increase the 'start' argument. Something like this:

```
item_count = 600
for i in range(0, item_count, 40):
    link = "http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dprice_asc&sid=tyy%2C4io&layout=grid&ajax=true&start=%d" % (i+1)

    // Do something with the link
    print link
```

Enjoy,
Wout