# 'Show more results' while scraping mobile details from flipkart

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My question is same as [Scraping all mobiles of Flipkart.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775742/scraping-all-mobiles-of-flipkart-com). I tried the solution given over there, but that change in the start variable is not working , and I can only scrape the starting twenty mobile information only.

```
import urllib#.request  # for py 3.x
import re  #regural expression for data manipulation
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url="http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy%2C4io&start=50"

regex = '<a href=(.+?)>'  # it will find the title
pattern=re.compile(regex)

htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)  #//.request is in 3.0x

htmltext= htmlfile.read()

docSoup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
abc=docSoup.findAll('a')





title=re.findall(pattern,c)

for i in title:
    print i
```

The initial value of start was 21, so increased to 50, but still I am getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 ajax request for the page,check the screenshot,try to code which dynamically change the start in each request,use try catch to handle exception handling [image: image page]

Answer (score 1):

When the website shows more, it sends another request which you have to send as well:

```
http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&start=61&ajax=true

http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&start=81&ajax=true
```

I found that using httpfox but you can also use chrome network to do it

Note that the first request has `start=61` and the second `start=81`

By the way i'd personaly use [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) isntead of urllib